# magit-version in Emacs 24.4 on Windows returns Wrong argument type: stringp, nill

Tags: magit

This works fine on the Mac, but when trying to set it up on Windows it didn't work.

I have msysGit Bash already on the windows path and tried setting as per other instructions.

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "bash")
(setq shell-file-name explicit-shell-file-name)
(setenv "SHELL" "bash") 
(setq explicit-bash-args '("--noediting" "-i"))
(setq w32-quote-process-args ?\")
(setenv "PATH"
    (concat ".:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:"
        (replace-regexp-in-string " " "\\\\ "
            (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\" "/"
                (replace-regexp-in-string "\\([A-Za-z]\\):" "/\\1"
                    (getenv "PATH"))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
(setq debug-on-error t)
```

And re-ran the command `M-x magit-version` to get the output:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  string-match("cmd\\.exe" nil)
  (if (string-match "cmd\\.exe" tramp-encoding-shell) "/c" "-c")
  eval((if (string-match "cmd\\.exe" tramp-encoding-shell) "/c" "-c"))
```

I then set

```
(setq tramp-encoding-shell explicit-shell-file-name)
```

And everything starts working properly.